# Get duration of a .WAV file with Qt

Tags: qt, audio, wav

how can I easily get the duration of a .WAV-file with Qt? I looked up different classes, but none of them seem to have an easy method to get this.

Answer (score 2):

A call to `QMediaPlayer's` [duration](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#duration-prop) function returns the duration of the current media, in milliseconds.